# Появление лишних колонок при работе с csv в r

Tags: csv, r

Работаю в Rstudio с csv файлом. Мне надо написать функцию, в которой последовательно выполняются некоторые операции над таблицей. Все операции прописаны правильно и по отдельности работают без ошибок, однако, если скомбинировать их в одну последовательность, допустим сначала заменить все NA значения на какие-то числа, а потом провести нормализацию таблицы, то NA сохранятся и соответственно не нормализируются. Я решил попробовать написать функцию записи в файл

```
write.csv(data, file = "C:/Users/User/Documents/data.csv")
```

а перед выполнением второй операции (нормализация/...) снова открыть файл

```
data <- read.csv(file = "C:/Users/User/Documents/data.csv", header = TRUE)
```

Последствия первой операции сохранились, все NA были заменены/удалены, но теперь слева от первой колонки появилась колонка x, в которой прописаны номера строк. При повторном закрытии и открытии файла появляется х.1 и так далее. Колонка очень мешает, не понимаю откуда она взялась и как убрать ее.

Как сохранить результат изменений первой операции, чтоб вторая работала уже с новой таблицей и не появлялся столбец х?

Буду рад любой помощи, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте аргумент `row.names = FALSE` функции `write.csv`, чтобы отключить запись имён строк.